# Scroll Multiple Text Fields using Action Script 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs5

I am trying to build a Flash application which would display data from a external source and scroll it from left to right.

I am new to action script world, i have found an example in which text is scrolling but here there is only one text field. I would like to have multiple text field depending upon my data loaded from external source. How can i achieve it. Do i need to create 10 text fields if my external data returns 10 records.

Any advice on this would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your task, if you need 10 lines of text information that moves independently, so you will need 10 text fields. Or you could scroll one text field and change it's content with a new information (next record). For scrolling of the text field you will need `Timer` or `Enter frame handler` or `Tweening engine`, as for changing text you will need some logic, like if text goes offscreen - show another text data.

For me, your question looks very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22401125/as3-error-text-linkage-to-xml/22401571#22401571), check it, maybe it will be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas for your insights. I did accomplish the task by having multiple text fields and scrolling them by enter frame handler, Thanks,